# Disable Visual Studio autocomplete

Tags: c++, formatting, visual-studio-2019

Using Visual Studio 2019 Professional to edit C/C++ files. Say I type:

```
for (int pos=0; pos < 7; pos++)
```

Now on the same line or the next, when I type `{`, Visual Studio automatically inserts the closing brace as if you had typed `{}`. Similarly, if I type:

```
std::string tmp =
```

As soon as I type `"`, this is auto-completed to `""`. Final example is `/*` which is automatically changed to `/**/`.

With too many years muscle-memory typing these myself, I'm constantly having to delete them and getting annoyed...how do I turn this off?

I've tried:

- Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Formatting and turned most options off
- Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced and disabled
- ...Brace Completion > Complete Parentheses in Raw String Literals
- ...Brace Completion > Complete Multiline Comments
- ...Intellisense > Disable Auto Updating
- Finally, I've closed and re-opened Visual Studio

And the auto completion is still happening.

Comment: Are you sure you've to _delete them_? Because if you type `"` there, it inserts `""` and places your cursor in between them and if you again type `"` then it simply shifts your cursor to the end; the content still being `""`.

Comment: @brc-dd: Yes, I delete them. Whether I *have to*, or even *should*, delete them is a separate matter and not relevant to the question.

Comment: It's relevant to the question since your original problem is that you *have* to delete them and that's annoying you. If you don't *have* to delete them then your problem is solved.

Comment: @JohnFilleau: Argh! I'm *having* to delete them because of muscle memory. I *could* choose to re-wire my brain, but I'd rather save the stress and have VS behave like a bunch of other editors I use! :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you want is under:

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > General > Automatic Brace Completion
```

Comment: Thanks. You know, I definiltely set this when Visual Studio was installed two weeks ago (but I forgot about the setting until now). Is there a known bug where settings revert to default under some circumstances, like an update or applying a license key? I recently applied the Professional license key supplied by work andVS may have done an update (not sure about the latter).

Comment: No idea. VS Community and VS Professional are technically different software, so they may have different configurations and user profiles. Maybe you were using Community 2019 and you got side graded to Professional 2019? Anyone's guess.