# How to disable single-quote auto-completion within JS and TS in Visual Studio but not brace completion

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, text-editor

This is the specific behavior I don't like:

[image]

Clearly no one wants the apostrophe in a comment turning into two apostrophes with the cursor placed between them.  However, there doesn't seem to be a way to disable single-quote auto-completion (let alone tell it to ignore when inside comments) without [turning off all brace completion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61502790/2704659).

Anyone have any suggestions?